# Analytical solution integral

Tags: integration, physics, mathematical-physics, computational-mathematics

Not sure if this is the correct place to ask this computational mathematics question but I have the following set of equations:

$$ x(t) = x_0 \psi, \qquad y(t) = \kappa \ln \psi - x_0 \psi +1,\qquad z(t) =-\kappa\ln \psi$$

with

$$
t- t_0 = \int ^\psi_{\psi_0} \frac{d\eta}{\eta(1+\kappa\ln \eta + x_0 \eta)}.
$$
Here $t$ represents time. I would like to plot these equations in python for the time range $t\in[0,1000]$. Of course, plotting $x,y$ or $z$ should be no problem.

However I am struggling to generate this plot. I am not looking of anyone to actually do this for me, but can I get a pointer on how to approach this? In particular, how should I generate the required $\psi$ for this problem given $\psi_0, x_0$ and $\kappa$?

Comment: [Cross-posted on Scientific Computing](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/27912/7574). Please do not do this as it causes redundancies and is disrespectful of the people who try to help you.